# PHP errors: mysqli_query() and mysqli_fetch_row() expects parameter 1, null is given?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

This is part of a PHP pagination script I'm working on which handles retriving data from MySqli:

```
<?php

include_once("/*****/access/connect.php");

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM article_index";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
// Error given for the line above: Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
// Error given for the line above: Warning: mysqli_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given

$rows = $row[0];

$page_rows = 5;

$last = ceil($rows/$page_rows);

if($last < 1){
    $last = 1;
}

$pagenum = 1;

if(isset($_GET['page'])){
$pagenum = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_GET['page']);
}

if ($pagenum < 1) { 
   $pagenum = 1; 
} else if ($pagenum > $last) { 
   $pagenum = $last; 
}

$limit = 'LIMIT ' .($pagenum - 1) * $page_rows .',' .$page_rows;

$sql = "SELECT datecode, name, date, link, category, tag FROM article_index ORDER BY datecode DESC $limit";

$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

// more code follows below, but is not relevant to my problem.
?>
```

This code, when run, returns *Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given*, and *Warning: mysqli_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given*.

The locations of the errors are indicated on the code.

I also have an external script that connects to my database:

```
<?php
DEFINE ('DB_USER', '******');
DEFINE ('DB_PASSWD', '******');
DEFINE ('DB_HOST', '******');
DEFINE ('DB_NAME', '******');

$conn = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWD, DB_NAME);

if(!$conn){
    die('Database connection error');
}

echo 'Connected to database'
?>
```

The connect script echos the 'Connected to database' message.

I'm not very familiar with PHP syntax at the moment, so I don't really understand what he error means or how to fix it. If anyone can help it would be much appreciated.

Comment: $conn is null, meaning you didn't set the connection. I assume that is happening in your include file, so take a look at that file.

Comment: Change include_once to require_once to make sure the file path is correct.

Comment: @Augwa I have edited my question to include the connection script. It tells me that it connected to the database so I'm not sure what's wrong with it.

Comment: well the actual problem is your include_once statement. You've included this file somewhere else in your code so the file is never included again at the part of your code execution, thus the variable is never created.

Comment: interchange your query and check the result. $query = mysqli_query($sql, $conn);

Comment: @Augwa Thanks for the info! Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: rewrite your code :D If you have this in a function you could simply remove the include statement and just add global $conn, and that's also assuming you did this include outside a function call. It's really tough to give you a straight answer without knowing how you structured everything. alternatively as well you can let it just simply make another connection by just telling it to include the file, but that will then blow up on your constants so you'll need to change those to variables. I don't really recommend it either as it's horribly inefficient.

Comment: `mysqli_query` should not expect argument to be `mysqli_result`, that makes no sense. Also, `var_dump()` the variables it's complaining about. Figure out what they are. Confirm what they should be. Trace back and debug to figure out why they aren't what they should be.

Answer (score 0):

check first that you are able to connected with db first.

```
 include_once("/access/connect.php");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error(); exit;
}


$sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM article_index";
if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {

/* fetch associative array */
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
    $rows = $row[0];

    $page_rows = 5;

       $last = ceil($rows/$page_rows);
       if($last < 1){    $last = 1; }
       $pagenum = 1;
       if(isset($_GET['page'])){ $pagenum = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '',    $_GET['page']); }
       if ($pagenum < 1) {     $pagenum = 1;  } else if ($pagenum > $last) {    $pagenum = $last;  }
       $limit = 'LIMIT ' .($pagenum - 1) * $page_rows .',' .$page_rows;
       $sqlnew = "SELECT datecode, name, date, link, category, tag FROM    article_index ORDER BY datecode DESC $limit";
      $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlnew);

}

/* free result set */
mysqli_free_result($result);
```

}